# query of sorting by year and adding the column value

Tags: c#

I am doing a C# project and I have the following scenario:

The first is for the month, the second is for the year and a button by the side. I also have a table which contains two columns named date (datatype small datetime) and price (varchar).

I have generated this but it errors with "Invalid column name 'yourMonthSelected' and
"Invalid column name 'yourYearSelected'".
is my approach the right way?

Comment: yess sir it helped a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you query text is wrong. You tried to add `yourMonthSelected` and `yourYearSelected` as a parameter in your query, but you didn't specify them in your query with `@yourMonthSelected` and `@yourYearSelected`.

Try this query;

```
string intero = "select sum(no_of_mobiles) from table2 where datepart(mm,given_schedule)= @yourMonthSelected and datepart(yy,given_schedule)= @yourYearSelected";
```

Look at [*`AddWithValue`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) method and check how you can use it. And you can write;

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

instead of

```
SqlDataReader rdr;
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Which they are exactly same but first one looks better. Also in your while clause, you should use `rdr[0]` instead of `rdr`, because `rdr` is an `array`. Like this;

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
     label2.Text = rdr[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: yess sir thank you really sir for helping me and is it compulsion to use @yourMonthSelected,@yourYearSelected "@" on each case?
and according to array rdr[0] why it is 0??

Comment: @shariq_khan `rdr[0]` means first row of your sql results. Since your sql query returns only one value / row (sum of no_of_mobiles) there is no problem. But remember `rdr` is an `array`.

Comment: sir i got what you told can you help me in query if i want to add the total no. of rows and count no. of rows present by sorting month and year. what i should make edit in that query.